# Losing everything - ways get money for an emergency

Tags: international-travel

This post is halfway related to [How does one recover from a (personal) disaster while abroad, travel-wise?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9987/how-does-one-recover-from-a-personal-disaster-while-abroad-travel-wise)

Imagine that you lose everything that you got (money, cell-phone, IDs) while abroad. I know I should have two forms of ID, not carry all the money in one pocket and stuff like that. But even then, stuff could happen. I'm into outdoor sports and sometimes extreme cases are not avoidable. Anyway. The only option I can think of is going to a consulate (I'm aware that they don't care much for people abroad in such conditions) and asking for some additional ID, then trying to find free WIFI and contacting someone back home to send me money through Western Union.

What are the other backup plans? I wish I could obtain money just with a password from an ATM or Western Union. Or even better, I wish I could deposit an envelope with some form of ID and pocket money and get it through expedited delivery from UPS at a business location.

Comment: Well, it's not just about a disaster, but ways that money could be send to you. I want to know if Western Union is the only one. Western Union requires some form of ID. I specially want to know how to get money without an ID. This is specially important, because sometimes you need money to obtain an ID.

Comment: You don't need ID to get a Western Union transfer, which is why it's a common form for money scams in the UK.  You just need the transaction ID, which the sender can provide to you over the phone.

Comment: @MarkMayo at least in Germany you need a passport / ID

Comment: Western Union has a major competitor called MoneyGram. Neither exist in some countries - including Japan! Be aware that there are scams involving using your stolen ID to get victims' friends and families to send emergency money to scammers pretending to be you. So take some measures to prove that you are the real you and for friends and families to ignore any requests not coming from you.